# Why I'm getting "The specified path does not exist" when trying to execute a shortcut from external apps of cmd and file explorer - C++ / Windows

Tags: c++, windows, file, file-not-found

I'm not a master of opretive systems and kind of not understanding this.

I saved web shortcut to YouTube from Chrome, and I have installed RocketDock, so I tried to add it as an element but it marked "The specified path does not exist" and went to the file path with the file explorer, executed it correctly, so I thougth it might was an app bug and tried to make a C++ program to execute the shorcut.

[image]

Before attempting to build the C++ app, I did this CMD command that worked perfectly:

`cd /Users/MyUser/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/"Start Menu"/Programs/"Chrome Applications" & YouTube.lnk`

Then I wrote the next C++ code in order to execute that command on CMD and redirect RocketDock to generated EXE file:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char command [113] = "cd /Users/MyUser/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/\"Start Menu\"/Programs/\"Chrome Applications\" & YouTube.lnk";
    system(command);
    return 0;
}
```

Finally I compiled the code, executed it and got this message:

> C:/Users/MyUser/AppData/Roaming/Microsoft/Windows/Start Menu/Programs/Chrome Applications
> This path does not exist.
> Check the path, and try again.

As I stated, I'm not an expert on this or may I am a newbie. So, can someone explain what is happening?

Comment: I forgot to say that proably I'm overcomplicating this, but I would like to know what I'm doing wrong

Comment: I think you need && in your command instead of &

Comment: Same thing happens